# How to make sure validation takes non-empty values?

Tags: excel, vba

**List of values**

[image: LIST OF VALUES]

**Dropdown**

[image: DROPDOWN]

I have a code which takes in values from A2 till the last row and creates a dropdown. I want to modify it in a way in which the dropdown only contains non-empty values. Please check the image for better understanding

```
For i = 2 To LastRow1 + 1
        With sht.Range("A" & i).Validation
            .delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=DropDown!A2:A" & LastRowAT
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = "Value not present in drop down."
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
Next i
```

Comment: You could try only putting the filled cells into the formula. Or make sure there are no empty cells between the values in the drop down.

Comment: Your Code looks alright. What's the Error ?

Comment: @mikku I want the dropdown to only contain non-empty values. Check image "DROPDOWN". It has blanks in the dropdown

Comment: `.IgnoreBlank = True` you have already set this property. That shouldn't be the case.

Comment: The case could be these cells are not blank. Rather they have something in them, like spaces or any special character that is not visible.

Comment: @Mikku I tried the code and it still contains blanks. IgnoreBlank is for not giving an error if you don't fill in a value. If you do it through the normal menu in excel instead of VBA, ignore blank cells still includes blanks into the drop down.

Comment: @RithwikSarma .. My Guess is that your cells are not blank. They have spaces in them. Use `Len` to check is the cells are blank or rather select the cells that are blank, press delete and rerun your code.

Comment: @Mikku That's [**not** what the `Validation.IgnoreBlank` property does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.validation.ignoreblank).  To test it yourself, create a brand new workbook, put a value in cells A1 and A3, then in cell B3 create a new Validation whose source is `=A1:A3` - you will still see the Blank from A2 in the list.  `IgnoreBlank` just means "is the user forced allowed to *not* enter a value instead of having to select from the list"

Comment: @Mikku @erazorv4 I know it is a silly question and not related to the above one but I want to copy a range of cells from A of LastRow+1 to V of LastRow+1 where LastRow is the last row with data present in it. I am using the code ``` sht.range("A"&LastRow+1 : "V"&LastRow+1 )``` which is giving me an error. Can you please correct the syntax?

Comment: @RithwikSarma Usually you should open a new question for this. But the error comes from the : It should be `("A" & LastRow + 1 & ":V" & LastRow + 1)` Although you might also want to put () around the LastRow + 1 bits. For it to actually add up to each other. Like so: `("A" & (LastRow + 1) & ":V" & (LastRow + 1))`. Edit: Also note that the `":V"` could also be `":" & "V"`. For example if you want `"V"` to be a variable instead. like `":" & aVariable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a temporary working column, which can (optionally) be located on a hidden sheet.

Then, you can use `INDEX` to retrieve the values from the column (`INDEX(DropDown!A:A,ROWNUM,1)` - we just need to work out which row to get the data from.

A very useful function here is `AGGREGATE` - this allows us to use the functionality of things like `SUM`, `MIN`, `COUNTA` or `SMALL` while skipping Hidden Rows and/or Error Values.  In this case, we want `SMALL` (get the *k*<sup>th</sup> smallest number from a list), and we will be using `ISBLANK` to generate a `#DIV0!` error when the cell is blank.

For speed of calculation, this will only process the first 100 rows in Column A

```
AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(DropDown!$A$1:$A$100)/--NOT(ISBLANK(DropDown!$A$1:$A$100)), ROW())
```

The first bit (`AGGREGATE(15, 6,`) means that we want `SMALL` and exclude any rows with errors.  The last bit (`, ROW())`) means that on the 1<sup>st</sup> row we want the smallest value, then on the 2<sup>nd</sup> row the next smallest, and so on, until we run out of non-error values.

The middle bit (`ROW(DropDown!$A$1:$A$100)/--NOT(ISBLANK(DropDown!$A$1:$A$100))`) starts by taking the Row number for each cell from your drop down list, and divides it by 1 (if the cell is not blank) or 0 (if the cell is blank).  Anything divided by 1 is itself, yielding the Row number, and anything divided by 0 will give an error.

Then, we can feed that into our `INDEX` formula as the Row to retrieve, like so:

```
=INDEX(DropDown!$A:$A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(DropDown!$A$1:$A$100)/--NOT(ISBLANK(DropDown!$A$1:$A$100)), ROW()), 1)
```

Then, you can assign your Drop Down to that list (or, set up a dynamic Named Range that will automatically resize, such as `=OtherDropDown!$A$1:INDEX(OtherDropDown!$A:$A,COUNTA(DropDown!$A:$A),1)`)